# Reading and parsing an arbitrary xml structure in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

New to XML parsing.I need to read a group of arbitrary XML files. They are all supposed to be POX, like the following format:

```
<someThing>
  <property1>blah blah blah</property1>
  <property2>blah blah blah</property2>
</someThing>
```

or the following:

```
<thingList>
  <items>
    <otherThing>
      <prop3>blah blah blah</prop3>
      <prop4>blah blah blah</prop4>
    </otherThing>
    <otherThing>
      <prop3>blah blah blah</prop3>
      <prop4>blah blah blah</prop4>
    </otherThing>
  </items>
</thingList>
```

So I won't know the name of the elements beforehand. My question is if there is any Java library that handles reading in XML not by the name of the node or the node's attribute, but by structure?

Comment: what do you mean by structure? have you tried SAX or DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using getRootElement method you can get the root element of the xml file. After getting the root element you have to specify the xml path which the element you want to get. I have written for "items/otherThing/prop3" using this, you get your prop3 tag value.

```
File fXmlFile = new File("test.xml");
     SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
     Document document = builder.build(fXmlFile);
     Element beans = document.getRootElement();

     Element dbUrlElementHost = (Element) XPath.selectSingleNode(beans,"items/otherThing/prop3");
     dbUrlElementUsername.getValue()+"";
```

Comment: This was the most robust answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getChildNodes()` to get the entire list of nodes, call this recursively in a method like `visitNode()`. This API is available in org.w3c.dom package.

First you call the `getChildNodes()` on the document's root node through the `visitNode()` method I mentioned and then within the `visitNode()` you again call `visitNode()` on each of the child nodes in the current node.

You can check the type by `getNodeType()`, and if it is `Node.TEXT_NODE` access the `getNodeValue()` to get the value of that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think DOM is best option if you want to go by Node. You may iterate through each node and it's list of child nodes. Here is good [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) to get an idea.